# Convert NSArray of NSDictionary into NSArray of dictionary values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Is there an direct way to convert an NSArray containing NSDictionary into an NSArray containing values of the dictionaries?

I have an array like this:

`a = [ { name = "A"},{ name = "B"}, {name = "C" } ]`

And I want this:

`a = [ "A", "B", "C" ]`

I can only think about iterating the previous array, and adding each field into the new mutable one, to ensure the same order. I'm wondering if there is a higher level operation or syntactic sugar that does that.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is build-in `map` function. But there are a number of third-part frameworks provide it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use KVC:

```
a = [a valueForKey:@"name"];
```

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ):

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using key on each of the array's objects.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know this. Brilliant. Will be changing some of my code tomorrow :D